# Magento ver 2.4.2 : in checkout payment method cash on delivery payment method, it shows the form to enter the credit card number

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.4.2, checkout-page

This form appears after selecting any payment method for the first time

Even if I click on cash on delivery in the payment method, it shows the form to enter the credit card number. Is this a virus?

And if I reload checkout page, this form automatically goes away

how to solve this problem?

Has anyone encountered this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this code of mallware installed at the end of shipping-sava-porecessor.js (image)[image]
The folder is located:
/public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor.js
Maybe it helps you.